# How to write HTTP post request in Unity by using UnityWebRequest?

Tags: unity-game-engine

`Mthod: Post
Link: www.link.com
Headers:
1: appKey="ABC" 
2: Content-Type="text/csv"`
How to write the C# Script to send the data through post.?

Comment: I gone through link, I tried examples also. Their it is specified that the form.add method is used to upload the header but it wont work. And I need the post request by using UnityWebRequest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public void Request()
{
    try
    {
        string url = "www.link.com";

        var request = UnityWebRequest.Post(url, "");
        request.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request.SetRequestHeader("Accept", "text/csv");
        request.SetRequestHeader("appKey", "ABC");
        StartCoroutine(onResponse(request));
    }
    catch (Exception e) { Debug.Log("ERROR : " + e.Message); }
}
private IEnumerator onResponse(UnityWebRequest req)
{

    yield return req.SendWebRequest();
    if (req.isError)
      Debug.Log("Network error has occured: " + req.GetResponseHeader(""));
    else
        Debug.Log("Success "+req.downloadHandler.text );
        byte[] results = req.downloadHandler.data;
    Debug.Log("Second Success");
    // Some code after success

}
```

This code is worked for me...

Comment: You can use promises with the UnityWebRequest to improve the quality of your code, check this OpenSource unity plugin => https://github.com/proyecto26/RestClient

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this :

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(PostCrt());
}

IEnumerator PostCrt()
{
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("appKey", "ABC");
    form.AddField("Content-Type", "text/csv");

    using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("www.link.com", form))
    {
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
        {
            Debug.Log(www.error);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Post Request Complete!");
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to call "using UnityEngine.Networking;" to be able to use UnityWebRequest.

Happy coding!

Comment: I am getting error of cannot connect to destination host. The link is server api link. It works when I paste it on browser but hear it si giving me above error.

Comment: Are you allowed to show me the full URL that you put there?

Comment: What this request exactly do? 
I think there is a problem of a missing Authorization header.

Comment: I added the appKey,and content-type, accept headers . These headers are sufficient to get response. I tested it through postman. I am not getting what is missing.

Comment: Strange, I don't think that the problem is from the request but I do think that there is a problem with the url redirection.
Sorry man I can't help you out.

Comment: No problem...Thank you for your support

Comment: could you able to tell me how to read the response from above code

Comment: Add a Debug.Log(www.downloadHandler.text);  when it is successful